# NullpointerExpection returned when back pressed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onbackpressed

I am sending the value from Activity A to Activity B and data is set to the view, it is working fine but when I press back button it is returning the `nullpointerexpection` in `textView.setText()` method . I have implemented as follows:

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
    serialArrayList = i.getParcelableExtra("member_list");

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.officerGrid);
    adapter = new DistrictOfficerGridAdapter(this, serialArrayList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemberDetailsActivity.class));
            Intent in = new Intent(DistrictOfficerActivity.this, MemberDetailsActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("name", serialArrayList.getTitle());
            in.putExtra("desig", serialArrayList.getPosition());
            in.putExtra("contact", serialArrayList.getMobile());
            in.putExtra("addr", serialArrayList.getAddress());
            in.putExtra("blood", serialArrayList.getBloodGroup());
            in.putExtra("image",serialArrayList.getPhotos());
            in.putExtra("email", serialArrayList.getEmail());
            in.putExtra("desc", serialArrayList.getDesc());
            in.putExtra("website", serialArrayList.getWebsite());
            in.putExtra("land", serialArrayList.getLandline());
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

And the data is received from `MemberDetailsActivity` and implemented as follows:

```
    nam = getIntent().getStringExtra("name").toString();
        design = getIntent().getStringExtra("desig");
        contat = getIntent().getStringExtra("contact");
        addr = getIntent().getStringExtra("addr");
        blood = getIntent().getStringExtra("blood");
        image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        website = getIntent().getStringExtra("website");
        email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        landL = getIntent().getStringExtra("land");

   name.setText(nam.toString());
    desig.setText(design.toString());
    phoneNumber.setText(contat.toString());
    address.setText(addr.toString());
    bloodG.setText(blood.toString());
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).into(imag);
    web.setText(website.toString());
    emai.setText(email.toString());
    landline.setText(landL.toString());
```

Comment: have you initialized your textview? like textview=findViewById(R.id.textView)

Comment: yes..Its working fine when the activity is created but when backpressed its returning the null pointer exeception.@Akash

Comment: can you please share your logs here?

Comment: Which textview is giving the NPE?

Comment: Why you have called startActivity() twice in itemClickListener of gridView?

Comment: Where is the `textview` in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do one mistake here. You are calling your Activity twice so please remove one of them. Try with this

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent in = new Intent(DistrictOfficerActivity.this, MemberDetailsActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("name", serialArrayList.getTitle());
        in.putExtra("desig", serialArrayList.getPosition());
        in.putExtra("contact", serialArrayList.getMobile());
        in.putExtra("addr", serialArrayList.getAddress());
        in.putExtra("blood", serialArrayList.getBloodGroup());
        in.putExtra("image",serialArrayList.getPhotos());
        in.putExtra("email", serialArrayList.getEmail());
        in.putExtra("desc", serialArrayList.getDesc());
        in.putExtra("website", serialArrayList.getWebsite());
        in.putExtra("land", serialArrayList.getLandline());
        startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

You start activity two times.

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemberDetailsActivity.class));
```

remove this line. whenever you click on item activity opens two times that means activities are added into stack when you pressed back you did not get intent from activity that's why it is giving null pointer exception.